Rational function 'of' a function
Theorem 2.8 from Apostol's Modular functions and Dirichlet series in number theory says "Every modular function can be expressed as a rational function of J" (where J is Klein's modular function). I know what rational functions are but not what a rational function 'of' another function is. I would appreciate if someone could give me a precise definition.

It means that every modular function $f$ lies in the field $\Bbb C(j)$, see wikipedia. This is the smallest field containing $\Bbb C$ and $j$. See also this post.
